# Kotlin: wait for Async call to finish and then assign value to var and then return it

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a variable `loginToken`. I want to assign value to is as

```
var loginToken: String = getLoginToken()
```

Following is my `getLoginToken` function

```
private fun getLoginToken(context: Context): String {
    val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE)
    var token =  sharedPref.getString("token", null)
    if (token == null) {
        token = LoginManager(activity).getToken(onGetSuccess = {
                // I get token here, i want to assign it to token var
             }, onGetFailure = {
                // I want to set token as empty string
             })
    }
    return token
}
```

How should I assign value to `token` and finally return it only when I get the result of getToken call?

Comment: Do you want a async or a blocking approach?

Comment: use co-routines where your function can be a suspended function so that you just say getLoginToken.await()

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar I want to wait for Async call to finish and then assign value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android maybe this will help ?

Comment: The coroutine design pattern is there because it doesnt want you to use callback pattern. If you are using coroutines, you should design your approach around it. Still if you want to mix the two, this is a good read [Callbacks and Kotlin Flows](https://medium.com/@elizarov/callbacks-and-kotlin-flows-2b53aa2525cf) and for comparison between async patterns [Async/await vs Coroutines vs Promises vs Callbacks](https://blog.benestudio.co/async-await-vs-coroutines-vs-promises-eaedee4e0829), this is on js but concepts apply elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`suspendCancellableCoroutine`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html) to convert a callback approach to coroutines. So for a coroutine approach, we can do something like this:

```
private fun getLoginToken(context: Context): String {
    val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE)
    var token = sharedPref.getString("token", null)
    if (token == null) {
        token = runBlocking { getTokenFromActivity(activity) }
    }
    return token
}

private suspend fun getTokenFromActivity(activity: Activity) =
    suspendCancellableCoroutine {
            LoginManager(activity).getToken(onGetSuccess = {
                it.completeResume(result)
            }, onGetFailure = {
                it.completeResume("")
            })
        }
```

You can also use a locking approach. For example, using a [`CountdownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). (lock it before the `getToken` function and unlock when the result is ready in the callback.)

Comment: Shall we use runBlocking () because most of the places I have read we shouldn't use runBlocking(). any other idea is there ?

Comment: @Menu no it's an anti-pattern. `runBlocking` should be only used for test purposes.